# Running django migrations on windows for remote mssql db with native windows db drivers

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure

All my life I tried avoiding using microsoft technologies for development, but maybe as a punishment for my biggest sins in the past, I am now forced to use them.

I'm developing a django application on python 2.7 to be deployed on azure as a web app. I need to run migrate to create the initial db. I have to do this on the machine I'm developing, which is a Windows 7 notebook. Getting to the point; this is my database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'mydbname',
    'USER': 'mydbuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
    'HOST': 'mydbinstance.database.windows.net',
    'PORT': '1433',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
        'MARS_Connection': 'True',
    }
  }
}
```

When I deploy the application to azure, the app can connect to the db with this configuration. So I figured I need to be able to connect to the db with the exact same configuration. I've installed pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure modules, and installed the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 ODBC drivers. But when I run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get the following error message:

```
django.db.utils.Error: ('IM002', [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0)) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Normally I would say at first that this could be a problem with my django settings, but I can confirm that the application on azure can connect to the same db with the same configuration, so I think this is a problem with my local configuration. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I needed to create a dsn under Data Sources tab of Administrative Services on my local machine. Creating a dsn with SQL Server Native Client 11.0 solved the connection issue.